# Why is my database table not generated automatically from STS?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on a Spring Boot application. I'm trying to generate my database table automatically into my database.

I think I'm missing something, but I couldn't figure it out yet, so can you please help me understand why my database is empty even though I already created the database but the table isn't generated.

I'm working with STS 4 , Spring Boot 2.4.4 and WAMP (MySQL 5.7.31) and Java 11.

I created the project and added the MySQL Driver, Spring Data JPA and Spring Web dependencies when creating it.

This is my pom.xml

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is my application.properties file

```
server.port=8081
### DATABASE ### 
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bike?useUnicode=true&useJD BCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC 
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
### JPA / HIBERNATE ###
spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect


#logging configuration
logging.file.name=C:\logs\springboot.log
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %-5level - %logger{36} - %msg%n
```

I already created an empty database named bike, and I created the entity class & repository:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "bike")
public class Bike implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "model")
    private String model;
    @Column(name = "serialNumber")
    private String serialNumber;
    @Column(name = "purchasePrice")
    private BigDecimal purchasePrice;
    @Column(name = "purchaseDate")
    private Date purchaseDate;
    @Column(name = "contact")
    private boolean contact;
}
```

its repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface BikeRepository extends CrudRepository<Bike, Integer> {
    
}
```

and this is the execution in the console

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.4)

2021-04-15 13:50:17 - INFO  - c.e.d.SpringAngularDemoApplication - Starting SpringAngularDemoApplication using Java 11.0.10 on DESKTOP-F9N36EA with PID 3088 (C:\Users\hp compact\Documents\Dev_Tools\Spring_STS\STS_WorkSpace\Spring_Angular_Demo\target\classes started by hp compact in C:\Users\hp compact\Documents\Dev_Tools\Spring_STS\STS_WorkSpace\Spring_Angular_Demo)
2021-04-15 13:50:17 - INFO  - c.e.d.SpringAngularDemoApplication - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-04-15 13:50:18 - INFO  - o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-04-15 13:50:18 - INFO  - o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-04-15 13:50:19 - INFO  - o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2021-04-15 13:50:19 - INFO  - o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-04-15 13:50:19 - INFO  - o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.44]
2021-04-15 13:50:19 - INFO  - o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-04-15 13:50:19 - INFO  - o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1719 ms
2021-04-15 13:50:19 - INFO  - o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-04-15 13:50:19 - INFO  - org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
2021-04-15 13:50:19 - INFO  - o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-04-15 13:50:19 - INFO  - com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-04-15 13:50:20 - INFO  - com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-04-15 13:50:20 - INFO  - org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2021-04-15 13:50:20 - INFO  - o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-04-15 13:50:20 - INFO  - o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-15 13:50:20 - WARN  - o.s.b.a.o.j.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-04-15 13:50:20 - INFO  - o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-04-15 13:50:20 - INFO  - o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2021-04-15 13:50:20 - INFO  - c.e.d.SpringAngularDemoApplication - Started SpringAngularDemoApplication in 3.716 seconds (JVM running for 4.091)
```

Comment: It must be creating something else the application simply wouldn't start. So either you aren't looking at the database you think you are looking at, or the application isn't using the database you think it uses.

Comment: well I reinstalled the wamp server bcz i thought it might be the cause of the problem and I  created only one new database in it ... so there is no way I would get confused
the data base name in mysql is "bike" and I am using the same name in the application.properties.

Comment: Well there is something with it. If the database wouldn't get created the application will not start, it starts so the database has a table/schema. So either you or the application is looking at something else. You can set the root logger to DEBUG and see if you get more information (you could also do TRACE but that will flood you in logging).

Comment: well I moved the entity class into the same package as the main class which contain the @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation and the table was created in the db, but this is weird it's not my first time creating spring boot app .... even my old project work perfectly without putting the entitie's class within the same package as the main class. I used to work using this hierarchy : 

> src/main/java 
   -com.example.spring ( main class is placed here) 
   - com.example.spring.model ( entity classes are placed here)

Comment: I fixed the problem, it was my bad I created the sub packages the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens because if you set the name of the table, you make explicit that the table with that name exists. Try removing the annotation `@Table(name="bike")` and see what happens. I think it will create the table with the same name of your class "**Bike**". Another thing, when your table column names are the same with your proprieties declared in java, you don't have to specify the `@Column(name = " ")` annotation